Getting Object To Look At Mouse Cursor with TresJS or TroisJS
I am a threejs noob trying to get a 3D object to look at the mouse cursor based on this
example, it's exactly what I want to do but in my vue project instead of react and using TresJs or TroisJS instead of react-three-fiber.
I tried to do the same with in the TresJS playground but with no sucess, and I can't find anything that can help me in the docs.
Could someone please help me with that ? How can I do the exact same thing as the example but with TresJS or TroisJS ?

Did you ask on Tres' Discord for help? They are quite active.

Yes I did, but so far no answers :(, from what I've seen, they don't seem that active

Posted an hour ago haha give them some time especially during lunch time.

haha kinda impatient, being looking at the docs and searching for tutorials for hours lol. Thanks for the shoutout on the discord server !
